# What is the upper bound on $\frac{(1+c)ab}{ca+b}$?

Tags: number-theory

Where $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers? Can we even formulate a theoretical upper bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in case $a=b$ the (1+c) term cancels and the expression  evaluates to $a$. so there is no finite upper bound

Comment: Would it then be right to say that this expression is bounded by [0,a]?

Comment: I'm wrong, it could be bounded by anything. Thanks.

Comment: Bounded below by $a$, I guess...